# OpenVPN kill switch doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I need a kill switch which kills the outgoing connections if OpenVPN isn't running, because otherwise a VPN wouldn't make any sense - if it disconnects, and there is a connection, my real IP is released.

Let's say 1.2.3.4 is my VPN server address, and this are my iptables after I executed my kill switch script:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       192.168.0.0/16

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/16       192.168.0.0/16
DROP       all  --  anywhere            !1.2.3.4
```

Imo it should work just fine. But I can't connect to the internet, while local traffic goes through. Do you see a problem in this configuration?

My computer is a Raspberry Pi 3 in this situation, and I'm using OpenVPN over TCP and I've a Fritz.Box connected to WAN.

Do you see any errors? My script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check that OpenVPN is actually running.
running=$(ps -e | grep openvpn)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "No active VPN session found."
    exit 1
fi

iptables -F

# Get WAN IP
WAN_IP=$(wget -q -O - http://ipecho.net/plain)

# Configure IPTable rules
# Change eth0 to wlan0 (or whatever network interface is being used) for wireless
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j  ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 ! -d $WAN_IP -j DROP
```

It is assembled with the following sources: https://github.com/qbwaggle/vpnkillswitch/blob/master/vpnkillswitch.sh, https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/43djk3/generic_kill_switch_script_for_openvpn_linux/

I tried these scripts on their own too, but they aren't working too (I think it's the same error?).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that such things _cannot_ possibly "release the real IP" (which would involve talking DHCP to your router). What they do is merely prevent the IP address from being used.

Comment: If OpenVPN fails, whatever the reason for that is, programs use the way which isn't tunneled to the VPN server. The servers my client is connecting to get my real WAN IP address, which I got from ISP. That's something what connects the whole communication process to me. So it "releases the real IP" in my described way. Or am I wrong? EDIT: Maybe you mean the word "real" isn't that fitting, let's say original.

Comment: Ah, so you meant 'release' in the sense of 'reveal'.

Comment: @grawity Yep. But do you know something to solve the problem? :D

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Sure, why not? Had no time to fix the problem by myself, so if you've an idea, just tell me.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN allows the use of outside scripts when the following directive,

```
 script-security 2
```

is included in the client configuration files. Use the directives

```
up /path/to/executable/script
down /path/to/another/executable/script
```

to run these two scripts when the interfaces are being setup or torn down. In your case, *up* is irrelevant, but you may use *down* to bring down all network interfaces when the OpenVPN is brought down, so as to make sure that no traffic is leaked via unencrypted channels. Please notice that, if OpenVPN hangs or is disconnected, *so long as your client thinks it is connected* there will be **no leaks**, because the traffic is still being sent encrypted (and possibly compressed) to the OpenVPN server. Thus it is impossible to intercept it.

The *down* script may be written as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /sys/class/net  -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -exec sh -c '[ "$1" != "lo" ] && ip link set dev $(basename $1) down' something {}   \;
```

This brings down **all** interfaces, except *lo* which is needed for your pc to work.

Comment: Good idea to do it in another way. I will try next weekend. But do you have an idea what's wrong with my iptables?

Comment: @Jonniboy The error in the script you did **not** post is that it assumes the OpenVPN is over UDP, while you explicitly state yours is over TCP. The script you published instead should work.