# Allow outgoing connection only on specific VPN

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, openvpn, debian-jessie

I would like to configure my Debian 8 server so it is not able to make outgoing connections at all except for a specific OpenVPN host (which distributes IP addresses based on an IP pool).

My attempt was to block eth0 and allow only on tun0, but that way if my VPN disconnects for some reason, it wouldn't be able to reconnect again.

Any approaches on how I could try to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you seen this, https://superuser.com/a/1145872/255732 ?

Comment: Seems interesting. But how would I achieve an auto reconnect? If all interfaces are down, surely nothing can leak, but I also can't write a program which automatically reconnects to the VPN...

Comment: There is a misunderstanding: so long as you use *ping-restart* or *ping-exit*, the OpenVPN will try to reconnect. The interfaces will go down only when OpenVPN decides (after the number of retries you set) that there is no chance of getting another connection. You may then modify the *up* script to bring up the rquired interface (*eth0*?) when the openvpn is started up, and write a script that checks whether *openvpn* is running* and, if not, restarts it. Thatś all.

Answer (score 0):

```
route add <ovpn host ip> gw <your real gateway>
route add -net <ovpn host network> gw <your real gateway>
route add -net 1.2.3.4/24 gw <your real gateway>
route del default
```

Comment: There is more than one possible OpenVPN IP. Should a hostname be working as well?

Comment: Actually, it's an entire /24 subnet. Is this the only possible solution?

Comment: I know I could use a for loop. But isn't there a "cleaner", more convenient solution?

Comment: `man route`, please...

Comment: So ```route add -net 1.2.3.4/24 gw <real gw>``` should be working?

Comment: yes, it should be

Comment: Works perfectly. Just had to add my DNS servers as well :)